# Why do my game objects jitter when moving the camera?

Tags: 2d, box2d, camera, movement, qt

I'm moving from Qt Widgets' `QGraphicsScene` to Qt Quick's `QQuickItem` for rendering my game objects. One of the things this involves is setting up a scene and the view onto that scene, as this was previously managed by `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView`.

My naive attempt was to do the following:

```
void SceneView::centerOn(const QPointF &pos)
{
    if (mScene) {
        mScene->setX(-(pos.x() - width() / 2));
        mScene->setY(-(pos.y() - height() / 2));
    }
}
```

This works, but it produces this odd effect where some game objects "jump around" between neighbouring pixels while the camera comes to a halt while following the player:

[image: bad]

The player's movement is fine. The crate also does not seem to exhibit this problem (though its Box2D debug drawing marker does).

This is what it looks like when the player moves without the camera following it:

[image: good, sorta]

This is what I'd expect from the other game objects when the camera is moving; no movement whatsoever relative to the scene.

The old, correct movement looked like this:

[image: correct]

The old code:

```
void MapView::centerOverFollowedItem()
{
    QRectF geometry(mFollowing->pos(), mFollowing->boundingRect().size());
    centerOn(geometry.center());
}
```

([QGraphicsView::centerOn implementation](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsview.cpp#n1904))

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, that's awkward. My last edit revealed the answer to my problem (that I've been struggling with all day): `QGraphicsView` casts the camera x/y position to integers...

This is the solution:

```
void SceneView::centerOn(const QPointF &pos)
{
    if (mScene) {
        mScene->setX(int(-(pos.x() - width() / 2)));
        mScene->setY(int(-(pos.y() - height() / 2)));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 The [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) strikes again! :)

Comment: It would be so less humiliating if I just used a rubber duck instead. :p

Comment: Don't feel bad—it happens to everyone. ([Here's me a few months back.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140868/in-node-how-do-i-require-files-inside-eval)) I edited the title so people of the future can hopefully find this more easily.